# Align vertical tikz chain

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a pinout, and thought a chain would help to create the pin names and pins. However I can not align a tikz chain to the left or right side. I would like the nodes to be aligned based on their left/

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  { [start chain=1 going below, node distance=1mm, every node/.style={draw}]
    \node [on chain] {A};
    \node [on chain] {Basd};
    \node [on chain] {C};
  } 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is a pinout? Something like [one of these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinout)?

Comment: @cfr: Way to late: but yes, you are correct, that is a pinout. (after all your answer now helped me twice :) )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a more complex specification for the direction to align the nodes, together with an appropriate anchor. For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes,chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      start chain=1 going {below=of \tikzchainprevious.south west}, 
      node distance=1mm, 
      every node/.style={draw},
      every on chain/.style={anchor=north west}
    ]
    \node [on chain] {A};
    \node [on chain] {Basd};
    \node [on chain] {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: aligned left on chain]

The `positioning` library, which `chains` loads, allows the `below=of` syntax. The `going` is based on an example on page 552 of the TiKZ manual (`chains` library, section 46.3).

Comment: Brilliant, I tried `going below west` since I found another post mentioning that tikz would use `\tikzchainprevious`.`<anchorname>` but gave up. Thank you.